# Can Only Log In to Joomla Backend with Emergency Root User

Tags: joomla-3.x, login, global-configuration

I'm having trouble logging in to the Joomla backend.

The only way I can access the admin panel is if I add `public $root_user="username";` to the **configuration.php** file.

When I finally logged in, I tried changing the Global Configurations to set all ACL to their defaults so I don't lock myself out again, but I keep getting this message:

[image]

I've even tried adding a new Super User but then when I attempt to log in with the new user info it says the password is wrong or I need to make an account... not really sure what's going on at this point. Please help!

Comment: Could you please add the contents of your `configuration.php` to http://pastebin.com, but replace any sensitive information (database details etc) with `XXXX`! Please also mention your Joomla version and if you've made any core changes recently or installed any extensions

Comment: I'm running Joomla 3.5. Here is the pastebin link:

http://pastebin.com/XP3Ru3G6

I haven't installed any extensions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you have edited some core files and introduced a syntax error. Download files from the same Joomla version you are using and overwrite the current ones.

Answer (score 1):

Either your website was hacked or you (or an extension that you installed) have modified some core files. A quick resolution to this problem is copying over the Joomla files from a fresh Joomla install onto your website (minus the installation and the images folder).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried resetting the admin super user pass? Have try from the below link. You will need to have access to phpmyadmin, Try the last solution in the example:

https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password%3F

Hope it helps your problem!